# How to send custom HTTP messages to servers from the Linux command line?

Tags: networking, http

**Greetings**

I've been recently learning the concept of [***HTTP message sections***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages), due to its importance in the field of socket programming and HTTP server production.

I would like to experiment writing custom HTTP messages to different servers and analyze the outcome ( I don't want the browser or an API to automate this task ) without having to do it in a programming language.

Are there any commands for achieving this functionality in the Linux command line?

Comment: You could use ```nc``` or ```netcat``` (two names for the same command, usually one being a symbolic link to the other). There are a couple of versions of this tool (namely an original "traditional" version, and a "BSD" rewrite with additional features), but they both allow establishing a connection between bare IP sockets, either in TCP or UDP mode (although for HTTP, you're only concerned with TCP). Check out [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341518/how-to-make-an-http-get-request-manually-with-netcat)